# Why does maven not generate sources from test-classes?

Tags: java, maven, querydsl, generate

I have some test-classes using Querydsl for my unit tests.
Querydsl normally generates a query type class but if the classes are in the test directory the class will not be generated.
As soon as I put the files in the src/main and compile with maven it works fine.
Because I use the classes only in my tests I don't want to put these files in this directory. Can someone help me with that ? 
My directory structure
src/main/java 
src/main/resources 
src/test/java/  
src/test/resources

As I said putting the files in this directory "src/main/java" the query type class will be generated, but putting the files in this directory src/test/java/ the type class will not be generated.

Maven APT plugin which generates the query types used by Querydsl

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Please share your directory structure along with your maven logs

Comment: I edited my post, but I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by "your maven logs". Sorry working with maven is really new to me.

Comment: what is your command to start the Maven build?

Comment: In order to start the maven build, I simply click on compile in the ''maven Lifecycle'' (I think the corresponding command is mvn compile). I hope that helps. So I need another command to compile if the files are in the test folder?

Comment: try to compile files from cmd, with -> mvn clean install

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get a compilation error: cannot find symbol QTestEntity (that is the generated class).

Comment: Maven distinguishes between test and non-test [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). By default `mvn compile` will not compile test-code or generate sources for test code. Use `mvn test-compile` to trigger generation of source and compile the genrated test sources. Also make sure that your DSL2Java generation is triggered in the right phase

Comment: I tried mvn test-compile but I get the same error: cannot find symbol QTestEntit. 
How can I check if my DSL2Java generation is triggered in the right phase ?
In my "Question Post" I have added the plugin which should generate the query type class.
Can I modify this in order to "trigger the generation in the right phase" ?

Answer (score 1):

Can across this same issue.
I found this solution to also generate the 'Q' entities for test sources.
The trick was to use the *test-process* goal of the plugin. Adding it to the *generate-test-sources* phase generates them at the correct time (test-compile).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apt.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-source-entities</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-test-entities</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Note this generates the entities for both the *main* and *test* sources.